# C# WinForm multiple click event handlers for similar function

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, mouseclick-event

I have a few toolStripMenuItems that act as a useful links for a series of websites, a rough example of the code would be something like:

```
private void toolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
}

private void toolStripMenuItem2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("http://www.bing.com");
}

private void toolStripMenuItem3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("https://www.duckduckgo.com");
}

private void toolStripMenuItem4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("http://www.yahoo.com/");
}
...
```

Is there a more elegant way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to do is use the same handler for each one:

```
toolStripMenu1.Click += toolStripItemClick;
toolStripMenu2.Click += toolStripItemClick;
// etc
```

I would use the `Tag` property for this, set it when you're constructing the toolStripItems:

`toolStripMenu1.Tag = "http://www.google.com";`

And then define your handler:

```
private void toolStripItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var c = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;
    Process.Start(c.Tag.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Put urls in menu items tag and attach this handler to all of them (hope it works)

```
private void toolStripMenuItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(sender.Tag.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for nice and simple, will accept when post is old enough.

Answer (score 2):

"Mash" all of the event handlers into one and then use the `sender` to see what `ToolStripMenuItem` was clicked.

```
private void toolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(sender == toolStripMenuItem1)
        Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
    else if(sender == toolStripMenuItem2)
        Process.Start("http://www.bing.com");
    else if(sender == toolStripMenuItem3)
        Process.Start("http://www.duckduckgo.com");
    else if(sender == toolStripMenuItem4)
        Process.Start("http://www.yahoo.com");
}
```

Or as Artem notes use the `Tag` member of the `Control` to store the `String` representing which site to visit. Then cast the `sender.Tag` to a `String` and use it.

```
toolStripMenuItem1.Tag = "http://www.google.com";
toolStripMenuItem2.Tag = "http://www.bing.com";
toolStripMenuItem3.Tag = "http://www.duckduckgo.com";
toolStripMenuItem4.Tag = "http://www.yahoo.com";
...
private void toolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(sender.Tag.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also subscribe to click event using a lambda expression:

```
toolStripMenuItem1.Click += (_, __) => Process.Start("process1");
toolStripMenuItem2.Click += (_, __) => Process.Start("process2");
```